# How to do Multiple select in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf for my UI part. I have a query.I have created a student and linked with different department. now while showing the student detail, i have to show the all the department and as well as mapped department in the select box which allows the multiple selection of the department. i have no idea how to do that can some one help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do the work:

```
  <select id="multiSelectElementsSelected"
            name="multiSelectElementsSelected"
            multiple="multiple"
            th:field="*{departments}">

        <option th:each="department,row : ${collectionOfDepartments.values()}"
                th:value="${department.value}"
                th:text="${department.label}"></option>
    </select>
```